# InvalidArgumentError during model training with custom EarlyStopping in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am working on a project in Colab, combining ready-made codes from Kaggle with a self-created dataset consisting of 1433 photos and four classes. The code ran smoothly until the point where I applied custom early stopping. However, I encountered an error during the following stage:

```
custom_early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss", patience=10, min_delta=0.001, mode="min"
)

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    callbacks=[custom_early_stopping],
)
```

The error message I received is as follows:

> InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: Detected at node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits defined at (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main

I am seeking assistance to understand and resolve the `InvalidArgumentError` error that occurred during the model training process. The specific error seems to be related to the `categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` node.

I applied a custom `EarlyStopping` callback during the training phase with the expectation of preventing overfitting but the error still occurred. I have already checked my dataset, the model architecture, and the code logic, but I am unable to pinpoint the issue.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you use the `tf.keras.Model` class then check the [fit method documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit). The `callbacks` and the `epochs` argument is good. You need input and target data as `x` and `y` arguments respectively. For the `validation_data` argument, you will also need **correctly formatted** data: NumPy arrays or tensors.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what should i add. Can you give  me more details?

Comment: If you go to the [model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) documentation, you will see you need `x` (input data) and the `y` (target data) argument. However, you have only one argument, the `train_generator`. I don't know the type of the `train_generator`, but I do know that you need arguments `x` and `y` for the `fit` method. Go to the documentation, and you will see that it can be a NumPy array, tensor, tensorflow dataset, or generator (I assume you will use this one).

Comment: TLDR: you need the `y` (target data) argument which should be consistent with the `x` (input data) argument. *Currently, you have only the `x` argument which is the `train_generator`.*